# CUDA Heap vs Global memory

Tags: cuda

I'm playing a bit with `cudaDeviceSetLimit()`, trying to see the maximum size allowed to set for my GPU.

Here I get unexpected results:

[image]

The Heap size stops increasing after 17.6 Gb, so I guess this is the maximum value I can set.
But since my GPU has only 16 Gb of memory (as confirmed by querying the device props), how is it possible for the Heap size to be greater?

Comment: It must be virtual addressing capability that can join multiple cards into single unified addressing or just virtual memory limit per process. Maybe the extra ~1.8GB coming from a second low-end graphics card or system memory?

Comment: On a GPU with 24GB memory, I can see the same limit of 17681179680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is not related to the actual memory size. Just because you can set a particular limit does not mean that you will have that much available memory to allocate.  This should be self-evident.  I can set the heap limit to say 14GB, and then do a `cudaMalloc` operation for 14GB.  If my GPU only has 16GB, both operations can succeed, but that does not mean I actually have 14GB of heap space "reserved".

The amount of heap space available is the lesser of the heap limit (minus any heap allocations already done) and the actual available GPU memory at that point.